# Calling a class method from a different file using Schedule Module in Python

Tags: python, typeerror, schedule

I'm trying to call a method from a class that is in a different file. This is how my code looks:

**main.py**

```
###Imports
import funct as f
import schedule
import time
###More Imports

###Grabbing GPS data from user and assigning values

bboxsize = f.find(userLat, userLng, userRad)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    r = f.find.radar(bboxsize) ### <---- Line 14
    schedule.every(5).seconds.do(r)
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)
```

**funct.py**

```
###Imports

class find:

    def __init__(self, userLat, userLng, userRad):
        self.userLat = userLat
        self.userLng = userLng
        self.userRad = userRad

    def bboxFormula(self):
    ### Lots of code that is not important to this
    return bboxsize

    def radar(self, bboxsize):
        api = OpenSkyApi(username='###', password='###')
        states = api.get_states(bbox=bboxsize)
        print(f"vvvvvv| {time.ctime(time.time())} |vvvvvv")
        print("------------------------------------------")
        for s in states.states:
            print("Callsign: %r, Latitude: %r, Longitude: %r, Altitude (meters): %r, Velocity %r)" % (s.callsign, s.latitude, s.longitude, s.geo_altitude, s.velocity))
        print("------------------------------------------")
```

When running this I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/##/##/##/##/main.py", line 14, in <module>
    r = f.find.radar(bboxsize)
TypeError: find.radar() missing 1 required positional argument: 'bboxsize'
```

I can run all of this in one file without classes, so I know it works. I have been messing with this for a while getting all sorts of errors with every change I make.

Is there something that I'm missing or is there no way for me to do this with the Schedule Module?

Comment: `find` is a class; you are trying to call an instance method without using an instance of the class. (Or rather, you are calling the method in an unorthodox way, and failing to provide the *other* argument it expects.)

Comment: `obj = f.find(...); bboxsize=...; r = obj.radar(bboxsize)`.

Comment: @chepner On top of main.py I assigned the GPS data that I gathered to userLat, userLng, userRad. Using them as params for the method f.find (aka bboxFormula) to return 2 sets of lat and longs to create a bounding box (bboxsize). Then use f.find.radar(bboxsize) to print a string of data collected from the API, with Schedule to update that data every 5 seconds. I gave each method a param, so I don't understand why it's not running. Maybe my thinking is wrong, would you not use class as a "folder" for functions to be called upon when needed?

Comment: @chepner Would it be better if I just deleted the class all together and just leave the definitions in a file by themselves?

Comment: Your `radar` function doesn't use its `self` argument at all, so either it doesn't need to be a method, or it should have been defined as `def radar(self): ...; states = api.get_states(self)`.

Comment: I'll just take it out of the class and leave it by itself in the file.

Answer (score 1):

I’m just guessing here, but I think you had different code when it was all one file.

Now with two files I think you meant to write this:

```py
find = f.find(userLat, userLng, userRad)
boxsize = find.bboxFormula()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    r = lambda :find.radar(bboxsize) ### <---- Line 14
    schedule.every(5).seconds.do(r)
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Honestly I've used lambda only once, I kinda understand the concept (creating a function without defining it), but do you mind explaining its use here?

EDIT:
I just tried it, came up with this:
```
  File "/Users/jacobesker/PycharmProjects/projectHermes/main.py", line 14, in <lambda>
    r = lambda : f.find.radar(bboxsize)
TypeError: find.radar() missing 1 required positional argument: 'bboxsize'
```

Comment: Ok, but that's your original error and you didn't use my code above.